# Angular2: Component doesn't update

Tags: angular, components

I am building an angular application about some projects I did. I have a detail page that shows the detail of a project.

**The problem:**
When I go to the project detail page, everything is correct.
But when I **switch the project variable** (by using the navigation I have on the page) the dependency component doesn't update, they don't get the correct project ID.

[image: Example image]

[image: Project structure]

**The projectdetail.html page that contains all the components:**

```
<div class="container-content" *ngIf="project">
    <div class="projectdetail">
        <div class="thumbnail header">
            <img [src]="project.img" [alt]="project.name" class="projectImage" />
            <div>
                <h2>{{project.name}}</h2>
                <!--The programming component that you can see in the image-->
                <programming-languages [ids]="project.languages"></programming-languages>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <carousel interval="5000" noWrap="false">
                <slide *ngFor="let slidez of slides; let index=index">
                    <img [src]="slidez.image" class="carouselimg" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Slide {{slidez.id}}</h4>
                        <p>{{slidez.text}}</p>
                    </div>
                </slide>
             </carousel>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail detail">
            <p>{{project.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="projects hidden-mm hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <projectsidelist [notShowId]="selectedProjectId"></projectsidelist>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The language component code:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ProgrammingLanguagesService } from '../services/programminglanguages.service';
import { ProgrammingLanguage } from '../models/programmingLanguage';

@Component({
    selector: 'programming-languages',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/programminglanguages.component.html',
    providers: [ProgrammingLanguagesService]  
})
export class ProgrammingLanguages implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    ids: number[];
    programmingLanguages: ProgrammingLanguage[];
    constructor(private programmingLanguagesService: ProgrammingLanguagesService) {

    }

    getProgrammingLanguages() {
        this.programmingLanguagesService.getProgrammingLanguages().subscribe(programmingLanguages => {
            var result: ProgrammingLanguage[] = [];
            this.ids.forEach((key: number) => {
                programmingLanguages.forEach((programmingLanguage: ProgrammingLanguage) => {
                    if (programmingLanguage.id == key)
                    {
                        result.push(programmingLanguage);
                    }
                })
            })       
            this.programmingLanguages = result;
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => this.getProgrammingLanguages(), 0);
    }
}
```

**The programming language html:**

```
<div class="languageoverlay">
    <span *ngFor="let programmingLanguage of programmingLanguages; let lastElement = last">
        <img [src]="programmingLanguage.img" [alt]="programmingLanguage.name" />
        <span [hidden]="lastElement" class="languageseperator">+</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**If you need extra code please ask or refer to the github**

*Github containing [All the code](https://github.com/Ghosttje/Portfolio-TestProject)*

*Explanation when you run the github: go to `http://localhost:3000/#/projectdetail/5` and click another project on the left bar. Then you see the issue!*

Comment: Could you provide more code?

Comment: I will do that tomorrow! :)

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski I added all the code and images

Comment: It's just the image that it's not updating?

Comment: @FabioAntunes Yea it is just the image that doesn't update correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were correctly passing an array of id's to the component but you never listen to the changes made so there is a quick fix for you:

in programminglanguages.component.ts change this code:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

to

`import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';`

and

```
export class ProgrammingLanguages implements OnInit {
```

to

```
export class ProgrammingLanguages implements OnInit, OnChanges {
```

and finally add this lifecycle function to you class body:

```
 ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.getProgrammingLanguages();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you import `SimpleChanges` if you don't use it?

Comment: it's only type declaration to changes, probably not required for him so he could go away without the parameter. I left it as I was checking the values :)

Comment: @MatWaligora I will check it this evening, and hopefully it will work :)

Comment: I downloaded your code from github and checked it, worked for me but as you know "weird, it's working on my pc" can happen any time. Let me know if it helped

Comment: @MatWaligora It actually works great :) Thx You earned the 50 point xD